# FIrebase Crashlytics strange crash log only on certain devices

Tags: android, crash, crashlytics

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange + 1314(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1314)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan + 680(SpannableStringBuilder.java:680)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan + 672(SpannableStringBuilder.java:672)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setText + 2474(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2474)
at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal + 10635(TextView.java:10635)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo + 7344(View.java:7344)
at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal + 7303(View.java:7303)
at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo + 7288(View.java:7288)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource + 146(AccessibilityRecord.java:146)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource + 119(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal + 7240(View.java:7240)
at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal + 10616(TextView.java:10616)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent + 7228(View.java:7228)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal + 7090(View.java:7090)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked + 7075(View.java:7075)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal + 7052(View.java:7052)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEventInternal + 11003(TextView.java:11003)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent + 7019(View.java:7019)
at android.widget.TextView.onSelectionChanged + 9537(TextView.java:9537)
at android.widget.TextView.spanChange + 9773(TextView.java:9773)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded + 12336(TextView.java:12336)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.sendSpanAdded + 399(SpannableStringInternal.java:399)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan + 222(SpannableStringInternal.java:222)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan + 152(SpannableStringInternal.java:152)
at android.text.SpannableString.setSpan + 46(SpannableString.java:46)
at android.text.Selection.setSelection + 78(Selection.java:78)
at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent + 218(LinkMovementMethod.java:218)
at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent + 9953(TextView.java:9953)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent + 11759(View.java:11759)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 3035(ViewGroup.java:3035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2664(ViewGroup.java:2664)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent + 464(DecorView.java:464)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent + 1867(PhoneWindow.java:1867)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent + 3297(Activity.java:3297)
at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent + 2(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:2)
at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent + 2(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:2)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent + 426(DecorView.java:426)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent + 11998(View.java:11998)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent + 5216(ViewRootImpl.java:5216)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess + 5030(ViewRootImpl.java:5030)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 4339(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext + 4392(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward + 4358(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply + 4366(ViewRootImpl.java:4366)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 4339(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext + 4392(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward + 4358(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward + 4501(ViewRootImpl.java:4501)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply + 4366(ViewRootImpl.java:4366)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply + 4558(ViewRootImpl.java:4558)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 4339(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext + 4392(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward + 4358(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply + 4366(ViewRootImpl.java:4366)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 4339(ViewRootImpl.java:4339)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent + 7118(ViewRootImpl.java:7118)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents + 7092(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent + 7053(ViewRootImpl.java:7053)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent + 7252(ViewRootImpl.java:7252)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent + 186(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next + 325(MessageQueue.java:325)
at android.os.Looper.loop + 142(Looper.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6710(ActivityThread.java:6710)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 240(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 770(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Hi devs, my Crashlytics gave me this crash log but it doesn't say which line of code in my program causes the crash. Any idea why this is showing? Only certain devices experience this crash and I suspect it is the spannablestring that is causing the crash which is strange to me because most devices have no issue at all. Also the spannablestring loads and working fine before the crash. Please let me know if you need more info to help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are some Accessibility logs... Maybe, you can try to reproduce after enabling TalkBack etc.. This may explain why few devices are reporting the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't reproduce the crash unfortunately with my devices. I managed to find something regarding Android Accessibility affecting spannablestring on some devices and is there a way to handle this crash? I am looking for a way at the same time but if you happen to know it, that would be great.